# 502 Error, IIS8 ASP .NET CORE AspNetCore.Antiforgery

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

So I have strange problem on production enviroment when publish to IIS8 (WINDOWS SERVER).
When I publish new code to production or staging (remote servers) users after publish gets 502 errors:

```
    502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

It's happen only in **Account/Login** and **Account/Register** views. All other views works correctly. 
The only one solution is to clear cookie **".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.pLfhSuGokUU"**. After that it works correctly.

Here is my startup configuration:
       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddLogging();

```
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<CaseweekDbContext>(opts =>
        {
            //Switch diffrent databases to diffrent enviroments
            if (CurrentEnvironment.IsProduction()){
                opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProductionConnection"));
            }else if (CurrentEnvironment.IsStaging())
            {
                opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("StagingConnection"));
            } else if (CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevelopmentConnection"));
            }           
        });

        services.AddScoped<DbContext, CaseweekDbContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, CaseweekUserStore>();
        services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<CaseweekIdentityRole>, CaseweekRoleStore>();

        // Add Identity services to the services container.
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, CaseweekIdentityRole>(identityOptions =>
        {
            identityOptions.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationTypes.CookieAuthentication;
            identityOptions.Password = new PasswordOptions()
            {
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = false,
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonAlphanumeric = false
            };
        })
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthorization(PolicyConfigurator.ConfigurePolicies);

        services.AddOptions();
        ApplicationConfigurator.ConfigureApp(services, Configuration);


        services
        .AddMvc(opts =>
        {
            FilterConfig.ConfigureFilters(opts.Filters);
        });
        services.AddSession();

        services.AddDbLogger<CaseweekDbContext, EntityFrameworkLog>((p) => new DbLogContextFactory());


        //configuring security policies
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ClaimRequirementHandler>();

        services.AddScoped<IValidatorFactory, ServiceProviderValidatorFactory>();


        DI.ConfigureServices(services);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        loggerFactory.AddDbLoggerProvider<CaseweekDbContext, EntityFrameworkLog>(serviceProvider);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
             app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSession();

        //Cookie authentication
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationTypes.CookieAuthentication,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Error/Forbidden"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });



        app.UseMvc(RouteConfig.ConfigureRoutes);
        app.UseIdentity();


        Seed(app);
    }
```